# How do I open SharePoint Page under PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

I have created a SharePoint Framework(SPFx) solution for custom development in SharePoint Online.

I have added the SharePoint Framework(SPFx) app to the SharePoint page.

Now, I need to open that SharePoint page in the PowerApps.

Is there any way to add a SharePoint page to the PowerApps?

It is something like opening a website link under the Android application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Power Apps does not officially support embedding external links within canvas application using default controls provided by Microsoft.

There is no default `iframe` control available within the Power Apps.

---

You can try using custom iframe component for your requirements.

You can get the custom component at: [iframePCF](https://github.com/yashag2255/iframePCF)

You can find other iframe custom components at: [PCF Gallery Search](https://search.pcf.gallery/):

[image]

**Similar thread(s)**:

1. [How to Embed Web Page/Web App Into Canvas apps](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-to-Embed-Web-Page-Web-App-Into-Canvas-apps/td-p/612401)