# Power Apps - How to display an iFrame on a Power Apps Screen

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps

we'd like to display documents in a SharePoint library on a Power Apps screen. Just executing the URL displays the document in a new tab; which is not what we want. We've been trying to put an iFrame on the screen but with no luck so far. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Power Apps does not officially support embedding external links within canvas application using default controls provided by Microsoft.

There is no default `iframe` control available within the Power Apps.

---

You can try using custom iframe component for your requirements.

You can get the custom component at: [iframePCF](https://github.com/yashag2255/iframePCF)

You can find other iframe custom components at: [PCF Gallery Search](https://search.pcf.gallery/):

[image]

**Similar thread(s)**:

1. [How do I open SharePoint Page under PowerApps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76445295/how-do-i-open-sharepoint-page-under-powerapps/76465157#76465157)
2. [How to Embed Web Page/Web App Into Canvas apps](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-to-Embed-Web-Page-Web-App-Into-Canvas-apps/td-p/612401)